# Undefined Index with $_POST even when defined

Tags: php, html, forms, post, undefined

So I'm making a login form using php and every time I submit it I get an undefined index error. Heres my form:

```html
 <form action="website.net/validation.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Username</label>
          <input type="text" maxlength="255" placeholder="Username" name="user" class="form-control" required />
          </div>

           <div class="form-group">
             <label>Password</label>
             <input type="password" maxlength="255" placeholder="Password" name="password" class="form-control" required />
           </div>
      <hr class="my-4">

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1" name="remember" value="yes">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Remember Me</label>
          </div>
          </div>
          <br>

      <p class="lead">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Login</button>
      </p>
      </form>
```

Heres the php:

```php
$name = stripslashes($_POST["user"]);
$pass = stripslashes($_POST["password"]);
```

That obviously just means that I've misspelled something or a value wasnt set, right? Wrong. I checked all of my spelling in the html and php, I've also done `var_dump($_POST["user"]);` and it prints out the username. The form element are *required* so they can't be not set. I've tried surrounding the variables with htmlentities(). I've tried surrounding them in an if then block testing for ifset. Nothing fixes this. I'm clueless as to why this doesn't work. Could someone help? Thanks

Whole php up to the error:

```php
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();
var_dump($_POST);
$name = stripslashes($_POST["user"]);
$pass = stripslashes($_POST["password"]);
```

Comment: `array(2) { ["user"]=> string(4) "Test" ["password"]=> string(13) "testpassword1" }`

Comment: Show the exact error message.

Comment: I'm confused. You said you did a var_dump() and the username gets displayed. So what seems to be the problem

Comment: I still get `Undefined index: user in /home/site/wwwroot/validation.php` and that stips the program from running

Comment: And the same thing for password

Comment: Post the whole script up to the line with the error message.

Comment: Is the PHP code using `$_POST` inside an `if` statement that checks if a form has been submitted?

Comment: @Qirel I don't think `validatin.php` is called unless the form is submitted. It's not the same script that displays the form.

Comment: Yes, if you look at the html the form has an actiom that calls the php

Comment: It seems to have fixed itself. Strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem seems strange but a good starting point would be to echo what the server seems to be seeing (fully structured). This can be done as:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
```

And seeing that you are using enctype="multipart/form-data", you can also dump the $_FILES. But I have a feeling that it could be one of two things: action field or stripslashes. For last option, why not pick them before cleaning, then clean. For the first option, can you change action field to be explicitly local:

```
<form action="validation.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: I unfortunately cant change the action field to be local because I host it on a separate server

Comment: Also do you mind explaining how to "pick them and then clean". Im 2 days new to php

Comment: Instead of **$name = stripslashes($_POST["user"]);** use: **$name = $_POST["user"];**